# Reshaping array by horizontal slices (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working with pretty big arrays of data, but here I'll consider a toy example.

Suppose `a` is 6x3 array:

```
a=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;10,11,12;13,14,15;16,17,18]
```

I want to reshape it to the array of size `(3,3,2)` by horizontal slices, so that the resulting array `b` would be:

```
b(:,:,1)= [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
b(:,:,2)= [10,11,12;13,14,15;16,17,18]
```

I was trying to do it with the reshape function: `b=reshape(a,[3,3,2])`, however, the resulting array is different (in goes though columns first).

I didn't really find the appropriate options for the reshape function.
Is there a nice solution to this issue? I know how to do it with a single for loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to reshape the transposed `a` matrix, then transpose back using `permute`.

```
b = permute(reshape(a.',3,3,2), [2,1,3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution requires a `permute` and a cheap `reshape`:

```
b = permute(reshape(a,3,2,3),[1,3,2]);
```